# Java Error: ')' expected

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("Enter a department name:");

String firstDepartment = bufRead.readLine();

System.out.println("Enter number of employees:");

val1 = Double.parseDouble(bufRead.readLine());

System.out.println("Enter cost per employee:");

val2 = Double.parseDouble(bufRead.readLine());

System.out.println("Enter sales:");

val3 = Double.parseDouble(bufRead.readLine());

System.out.println("Hello, Donaldio! Your " + firstDepartment + "profit is " "$" + (val3 - val1 * val2));

String pleaseContinue = bufRead.readLine();

System.out.println("Please press enter!");
```

This is just one part of my code. Unfortunately, the command prompt keeps telling me there's an error at

```
System.out.println("Hello, Donaldio! Your " + firstDepartment + "profit is " "$" + (val3 - val1 * val2));
```

It says that there's a ')' expected. I understand what it means, but I can't find where the parentheses is missing... I'm so confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are missing a '+' between "profit is" and "$"

Comment: You've got an extra quote in there, before the currency sign.

Comment: I suggest that you read every lines and ask yourself "can it be understood ?". If you always proceed that way, you will avoid many errors.

Comment: Use an IDE to write simple code

Answer (score 4):

You missed a `+` sign in between

```
"profit is " "$"
            ^
```

Based on the logic, I think you actually don't mean to include those double quotes:

```
"profit is $"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println("Hello, Donaldio! Your " + firstDepartment + "profit is " "$" + (val3 - val1 * val2));
```

should be

```
System.out.println("Hello, Donaldio! Your " + firstDepartment + "profit is $" + (val3 - val1 * val2));
```